# Enter keystroke event not getting dispatched

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, remote-debugging

Trying to send enter keystroke to headless chrome through remote debugging protocol. Here is the source code. Any help is appreciated. It doesn't seem to be working with Chrome 69. I have also tried keyIdentifier: 'U+000D', keyIdentifier: 'Enter' and key: '\u000d' in addition to windowsVirtualKeyCode: 13.

```
const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface")
const chromeLauncher = require("chrome-launcher")
const getPort = require("get-port")
const R = require("rambdax")

const chromeFlags = [
  "--disable-gpu",
  "--disable-sync",
  "--no-first-run",
  "--headless",
  "--window-size=1366,768"
]

const main = async () => {
  try{
    const port = await getPort()
    const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
      chromeFlags,
      port,
    })
    const client = await CDP({ port })
    const { Page, Runtime, Input } = client

    await Promise.all([
      Page.enable(),
      Runtime.enable(),
    ])

    await Page.navigate({ url : 'https://www.google.com' })
    await Page.loadEventFired()
    await R.delay(1000)
    await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'char', text: 't' })
    await R.delay(200)
    await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'char', text: 'e' })
    await R.delay(200)
    await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'char', text: 's' })
    await R.delay(200)
    await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'char', text: 't' })
    await R.delay(200)

    await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'rawKeyDown', windowsVirtualKeyCode: 13 })
    await R.delay(3000)
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Github Issue 45](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/45) , where you also got the above code from. Using the following works:

```
await Input.dispatchKeyEvent({ type: 'char', text: "\r" })
```